# How do I identify if my graphics card is the RX6600 or the RX6600XT?

Tags: amd-graphics

I got a used graphics card. It is supposed to be the RX6600XT. However I don't really know how to tell using the terminal.

I've tried:

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA
```

Which outputs:

```
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:73ff] (rev c1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:5023]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

The problem is `1002:73ff` can be the 6600, 6600XT or the 6600M. Does anyone know how I can tell which card I have?

This is an OEM card (Dell), so it doesn't say on the GPU housing anywhere.

Thanks so much.

Comment: did you try `sudo lshw -C video` ?

Comment: The subsystem identifier 1028:5023 suggests it is the RX 6600 XT. Please see: https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/248911/248911

Comment: @chili555 yeah I saw that but wasn't sure how reliable it was

Answer (score 0):

`sudo lshw -c display`

This should give you more detailed information about your graphics card, including the specific model and other relevant details

Comment: That just says `product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]`

Comment: Try updating drivers https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers